# How to skip missing additional images and continue to import products?

Tags: magento2, product-images, import-products

I am `importing` more than 10000 products to my **Magento 2** store and got the following error codes:

1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external
   resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 2

I knew I can fix this problem by `uploading` the `missed images` or `delete the row(s)`, but it's very time-consuming.

Is there any way to `skip` the `invalid images` and continue the importing procession since I don't mind that a few products missing some additional images?

Thanks.

Comment: can you increase the max execution time for the timebeing.

Comment: @inrsaurabh It seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked for me. I was uploading images from an external server and there were some images that were not uploaded(404) so while upload Magento was throwing the exception(not skipping), so I applied this solution.

Please do not try to override vendor files using a preference or plugin.

You can try with below method.
For Magento 2.4.X version

File Path:-
vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php

update function getFileHash with below code:-

```
private function getFileHash(string $path): string
{
    try {
        return hash_file(self::HASH_ALGORITHM, $path);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        return "";
    }
}
```